# jquery .fadeto effect flashing between images (tooltip) 

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery fadeTo effect for some tooltips on top of a table of a bunch of images.

This is working perfectly except for one detail. When I drag my mouse between the two image (which are touching) there is a brief "flicker" as it switches from the first images tooltip to the second.

I can't think of a way to stop this from happening. is there?

here is the javascript I am using for the tooltip which uses qtip.

```
   $('.tipper').each(function()
   {
      $(this).qtip({
         content: $(this).attr('tooltip'), // Use the tooltip attribute of the element for the content
         position: {target: 'mouse', adjust: {x: 20 }},
         show: { effect: function() { $(this).fadeTo(300, 0.9);}, length:0},
         hide: { effect: 'none', length:0, delay:0 },
         style: { border: { width: 2, radius: 0 , color: '#fff'} ,width: 200,  name: 'light', fontFamily: 'Arial', 'font-size': '12px', 'letter-spacing': 1, lineHeight:1.6, textAlign:'center', textTransform:'uppercase', fontWeight:'bold'},
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but maybe this would work better:

```
$('.tipper').qtip({
    content: $(this).attr('tooltip'), 
    // Use the tooltip attribute of the element for the content
    position: {target: 'mouse', adjust: {x: 20 }},
    show: { effect: function() { $(this).fadeTo(300, 0.9);}, length:0},
    hide: { effect: 'none', length:0, delay:0 },
    style: { border: { width: 2, radius: 0 , color: '#fff'} ,
             width: 200,  
             name: 'light', 
             fontFamily: 'Arial', 'font-size': '12px', 'letter-spacing': 1,
             lineHeight:1.6, 
             textAlign:'center', 
             textTransform:'uppercase', 
             fontWeight:'bold' },
});
```